# how do you remove a list from another list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have something like:

```
a = [4,3,1,6,3,5,3]
b = [4,2,6]
```

and I wanted to remove the 3 elements of b from a.  I was trying to do:

```
c = a - b
```

but I was thinking that the inverse of merge (`+`) might not be a thing, and was correct:  *Unsupported Operand types for -: list and list*.  I was contemplating just looping over them, but that just doesnt really sound pythony.

My end state is going to be:  `c = [3,1,3,5,3]`

If you had not noticed, b is not a subset of a and these are unordered.   2 different sets, these sets are not unique either, but only want to remove 1 instance per `i in b`, not all instance of `i in b`

**EDIT** It seems that the current answer does not resolve my question.

```
a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3]
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
#c result is [2,2,2,4,5]
```

I want c to return: `[1,2,2,2,4,5]`

For the sake of speed typing, I just put sorted numbers, but the lists ARE IN FACT unsorted, though for the sake of cleanliness we can sort them.
They are just unsorted at init.  *Since there are duplicates in list items, I can't use a set as per the definition of set.*

Comment: Are these sets or lists?

Comment: lists, sorry, wrong wordage

Comment: Your last paragraph is not clear. If there is a `4` in list `b` and there are two occurrences of `4` in list `a`, do you want to remove one of the `4`'s or all of the `4`'s from `a`?

Comment: **For the Record**  The duplicates are not the correct answer, nor is ysearka's.....    DAX gave me the correct answer, as i only wanted to remove a particular number of instances, not *all* of a particular type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted you only want to remove the items once per occurrence:

```
for x in [tmp for tmp in b if tmp in a]:
        a.remove(x)
```

Comment: is it possible to not override a and just do assignment to a new varaible?  Just something like:`c = [x for x in a]\n  for x in [tmp for tmp in b if tmp in c]: c.remove(x)`

Comment: You could use e.g. aluriak's answer which has a few more lines but does not mutate your lists.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code:

```
[x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Comment: This is what i was thinking of, but couldnt get it down.  For some reason, i kept trying to leverage bitwise operation on the lists.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: "but only want to remove 1 instance per i in b, not all instance of i in b" -> if this is a working answer then please adjust your question, as currently your last paragraph conflicts with this answer ...

Comment: @DAXaholic you are in fact correct.  I ran the code snipperts and noticed this wasnt the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As input and output lists are unordered, use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a way to go:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [4,3,1,6,3,5,3]
b = [4,2,6]
c = list((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).elements())

print(c)
```

This solution handles the following case differently than [ysearka answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190134/3077939):

```
a = [4,3,1,6,3,5,3]
b = [3]
```

Where many answers here leads to `c = [4,1,6,5]`, the one using Counter will outputs `c = [4,1,6,3,3,5]`.

This behavior is also implemented by [DAXaholic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190200/3077939), but with modification of an existing list, which is not a pythonic way to go, and could be costly on big lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in b:
    while x in a:
        a.remove(x)
```

Now `a` is

```
[3, 1, 3, 5, 3]
```